# Cross sectional survey - difference in difference campaign evaluation

Tags: causality, survey, difference-in-difference

I asked this question on the econ form (https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/51805/cross-sectional-survey-difference-in-difference-campaign-evaluation) but I don't know how to cross post.

I would like to use two cross sectional surveys to evaluate the impact of a media campaign on public opinions. The problem is how to identify the "untreated" at baseline? Technically everyone is untreated and I will be using a recall question in the endline survey to separate the "untreated" from the "treated"? My question is basically should I use something other that DiD for this? How do I get two groups at baseline?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. Is one cross-sectional survey in the pre-campaign era and the second one after? To use the method you’re proposing, you need to survey two groups before *and* after the media campaign. The “treated” group is exposed to media campaign in the endline survey, while the “untreated” group is unexposed to the media campaign at both baseline and endline.

Comment: Thanks so much @ThomasBilach! Yes, exactly baseline survey will be before we launch the campaign and the second after it is over. What I'm hazy on is with a cross sectional survey how do I know which respondents in the baseline to compare the treated group to? So imagine doing a diff-in-diff I would need to create a variable that specifies treatment status, but I won't have any treated observation at baseline so it won't work right?